# Bypass IP restriction SSH

Tags: laravel, ssh, laravel-5, restrictions

I have a Laravel app with CI/CD setup at BuddyWorks which lets you create deployment pipelines.

I want to use SSH action to run some config scripts (artisan...) after uploading the source code.

Unfortunately, it turned out that SSH connectivity to the hosting server is restricted to my home country, ergo can’t use BuddyWorks to do the job for me. The hosting company refused my request to whitelist BuddyWorks IP’s.

So here am, looking for a solution to bypass restriction. 
Currently, I’m investigating SSH reverse for , but not sure I’m on good path.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Get a new host?

Comment: Keeping that as a "Worst case scenario".

Comment: A host that's actively blocking your IP and refusing to whitelist it is already a worst-case scenario.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The IP is not mine, it is a 3rd party service.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a small http->ssh proxy server with basic authentication which receives commands from pipeline via post requests and connects to the host server via ssh, executes the commands and logs to slack.